# Getting vertices as tuples in Python IGraph

Tags: python, igraph

How can I obtain the edges of a graph as vertex tuples in Python IGraph?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the documentation here: [EdgeSeq](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.EdgeSeq-class.html)

> The individual edges can be accessed by indexing the edge sequence object. It can be used as an iterable as well, or even in a list comprehension:

```
# for a graph g
g = Graph.Full(3)

# Get the edges as a list of tuples
edges = [edge.tuple for edge in g.es]
print(edges)
# [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```